# Can't get to recover the user information

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Profile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            nom: '',
            pnom: '',
            username: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const token = localStorage.usertoken;
        // alert(":"+token);
        // const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

        this.setState = ({
            nom: token.nom,
            pnom: token.pnom,
            username: token.username,
            email: token.email
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="jumbotron mt-5">
                    <h1 className="text-center">PROFILE</h1>
                    <table className="table col-md-6 mx-auto">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Nom</td>
                                <td>{this.state.nom}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Prénoms</td>
                                <td>{this.state.pnom}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Username</td>
                                <td>{this.state.username}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>{this.state.email}</td>
                            </tr> 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Profile
```

hi i'm working on a project with react as font-end and node js as back-end. I can't get to recover the user information. this is my very first project with react and node js

Comment: Hi Joel, welcome to SO. Could you please post the code where the usertoken is being set into local storage

Comment: did you try out my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
componentDidMount(){
    const token = localStorage.usertoken
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
    this.setState({
        nom: decoded.nom,
        pnom: decoded.pnom,
        username: decoded.username,
        email: decoded.email
    })
}
```

I found the solution, the problem was that I would not retrieve all the user information in my back-end

Answer (score 1):

You need to *call* `this.setState`, not assign to it.

```
this.setState = ({
            nom: token.nom,
            pnom: token.pnom,
            username: token.username,
            email: token.email
        })
```

should be

```
this.setState({
            nom: token.nom,
            pnom: token.pnom,
            username: token.username,
            email: token.email
})
```

or more succinctly

```
const {nom, pnom, username, email} = token;
this.setState({nom, pnom, username, email});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this for getting state from localStorage

```
localStorage.getItem("usertoken")
```

Also make sure your localStorage has the value. To test you can open your browser console try this:

```
userObject = {
 nom: 'samplenom',
 pnom: 'pnom',
 username: 'sampleusername',
 email: 'sampelemail'
}
localStorage.setItem("usertoken", JSON.stringify(userObject))
```

And your setState must be

```
this.setState({
 nom: token.nom,
 pnom: token.pnom,
 username: token.username,
 email: token.email
})
```